# How to determine the probability that a variable will exceed a given value given the value of a related variable.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have data relating an independent variable (I) to a dependent variable (D) and I want to use this data set to predict the behavior of the dependent variable given a measurement of the independent variable.  For example, suppose the data set is:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
 & \text{I} & \text{D} 
\\ \hline\text{Point 1} & 5 & 4 
\\ \hline\text{Point 2} & 8 & 7
\\ \hline\text{Point 3} & 2 & 3
\\ \hline\text{Point 4} & 7 & 8
\\ \hline\text{Point 5} & 5 & 5
\end{array}$$

Clearly there is a positive correlation, so that if the independent variable is large, it is more likely that the dependent variable will also be large.

The question I'm interested in is: **Based on this data, if the independent variable is measured to be  some value X, what is the probability that the dependent variable is greater than or equal to some other value Y?**  I am less interested the specific answer for this case than about the statistical methods needed to get the answer.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  You have the entire distribution, no?  So you can just read off what you want.  If, on the other hand, you meant that this table represents a sampling from some (otherwise unknown) joint distribution, then you will need to model that joint distribution in order to proceed.

Comment: @lulu This data is just a sample, so I cannot simply read off what I want.  To provide a little context, I need to monitor the value of 'D', however it is difficult to measure, therefore instead I will monitor the value of 'I', which is easier to measure and use it as an "indicator" of 'D'.  I need to know, for a specific value of 'I', what the probability is that 'D' will exceed a threshold quantity.  How would you model the distribution to determine this probability?

Comment: Right, but of course a sample can't tell you the "true" distribution for sure.  You need to model it.  Use the sample data to calibrate some model (like two correlated normal variables or whatever).

Comment: My concern with your recommendation is that 'D' is not a random variable since it depends on 'I'.  For example if I wanted to know what the probability is that 'D' is greater than 10, given that 'I' is also 10, using a bivariate CDF approach would surely say that the probability is low since the data for each variable does not extend that high.  However, the point (10,10) actually lies quite near the trendline, indicating that the probability should be about 50%.

Comment: Not following. You have two variables which are correlated.  Which one you call independent has nothing to do with the joint distribution, the fact is you just have two dependent variables.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you recommended.  Could you be more specific about how you would calculate the probability?

Comment: Not right now, maybe later. But, in any case, I'm not specifying a calculation, just saying that the first step is to model the distribution somehow. As a quick fix, you can just read off the answer as if the sample were the whole thing, but that's pretty bad if the sample is small.

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by "read off"?

Comment: Looking at your table, I just mean that you check all the values in which your preferred variable hits the desired level, and read off the observed values of the other.  The problem, of course, is that your data set probably doesn't have many instances at your value.  That's why it's important to have some model in mind.

Comment: A typical model might be a correlated [binormal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinormalDistribution.html).  The idea is to look at each variable separately to see if they look well approximated by a normal.  If they do, great!  Use the sample data to fit the parameters and then compute using those functions.  If they don't, well, try to fit them to some more familiar distribution.